# Jquery .show() and display:inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I am using this jquery code 
`onclick="jQuery('.hidden').show()"`
to show the class labeled .hidden
this is what the class looks like :

```
.hidden { display:none}
```

the issue is when it displays the class its a display:block;
I would like it to display it as display:inline;
that way its on the same line as the text that comes before.
any help would be appreciated been going crazy I googled almost everything related to it but nothing guided me to the right path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could append an explicit css attribute to the element:

```
onclick="jQuery('.hidden').css('display','inline');"
```

try this, i hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to add/remove the class .hidden from the element, if you want it to display inline, create a css class .inline with the appropriate css and toggle this on / off when needed. Or the other option is use an html element that is inline rather than block if possible.